# DAX for multiple values in a role table filter expression

Tags: dax

For an embedded Power BI report, using `CustomData`, I pass member id to a role in SSAS tabular cube. The role has a filter expression on `Member` table. The expression is `Member[MemberId] =VALUE(CUSTOMDATA()`. It works fine.

I would like to pass comma delimited multiple member values such as 1,3,9 so any of these members are allowed to filter through.
I have played with `IN`, `Containsrow` and `Allselected` but didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would go for a new table and a Many to Many relationship. Going for a Search and Mid would force you to only accept a limited amount of arguments, and a awfull expression to calculate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PATHCONTAINS` to determine if `Member[MemberId]` is in `CUSTOMDATA()`.  If you can't pass in a list separated by a pipe character, then you can use `SUBSTITUTE` to convert the delimiter to a pipe.

```
PATHCONTAINS(SUBSTITUTE(CUSTOMDATA(), ",", "|"), Member[MeberId])
```

Be warned that if there is white space in `CUSTOMDATA()` that it won't get matched.  That is if custom data is **1, 2, 3**, and member id is **2** then there won't be a match, since the second item in custom data includes the space.